# What are differences between coordinate balls and geodesic balls in applications?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $(X,g)$ be a compact Riemanian manifold. I wonder what are real, distinct applications of geodesic balls to make them stand out usual coordinate balls?

Thanks so much for any suggestions.

Comment: By "geodesic balls" you mean balls induced by geodesic distance (e.g think of a spherical cap on a sphere) and by "coordinate balls" you mean balls induced by the euclidean distance in the big euclidean space in which the manifold lives. Right ? Well, the former carries geometric information (e.g curvature) about the manifold, while the latter doesn't.

Comment: @dohmatob Yeah, for coordinate balls, I mean balls that are induced by coordinate charts. So they are not involved with the metric $g$. However, what I would like to see is some technical examples that we need to use geodesic balls to expolit the metric $g$ or as you said: "geometric information".

Comment: As an example application, geodesic balls are used in the study of isoperimetric inequalities on manifolds (see Otto et Villani 2000 https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0022123699935577?token=691FE95BCE80BEE6F386C1211A4B3F50E3C5455A32EADD9C627AB4BBD04254FCCE52632F800D674583B4CBE633FED927)

Comment: @dohmatob Hi, that is very technical.

Comment: Only superficially does it look technical. Suppose you had a piece of land of surface area $A$, which lives on a mnifold $(X,g)$ (here, the earth). What shape would you like this piece of land to be so that you have as short  a perimiter as possible to defend against enemy armies ? This and similar questions have been around for millenia, and can be studied / answered via isoperimetric inequalities.